# Where do I find hiking partners to go on glaciers/mountains?

Tags: safety, mountaineering, glaciers

Is there a well-known free webpage in Europe where you can find hiking partners to go on > 4000 m mountains?

For bouldering and climbing it is usually not a problem to find "new friends", since I always go at certain times to certain places. But this does not apply to mountaineering... Typically the people I go climbing with do not go on difficult mountain tours...

To me it is way more safer to go with other people hiking than alone.

Comment: What country are you based in?
If it has an alpine club then it is the easiest way - join it, meet people on tours and on club's forum.

Comment: Have you tried Meetup?  No 4000m mountains around here but we have a mountaineers group in town (pop 2M) so I wouldn't be surprised if there are others.

Comment: Finding safe climbing and mountaineering partners can be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

For **Switzerland** I suggest contacting your local section of the [Swiss Alpine Club](https://www.sac-cas.ch/en/) (or you might directly sign up for it).
They have sections all over Switzerland in all major cities (and many many smaller towns and regions also) and have been one of the cornerstones of Swiss mountaineering for more than a century.

- You'll find like-minded people to join you on tours.
- You'll find guided tours, trainings and courses.
- The SAC also runs more than 150 mountain huts in the Swiss Alps, which you can use as bases (or destinations) for tours. Staying in the huts is cheaper for SAC members, but generally open to the public.

Answer (score 0):

You can find mountaineering partners on the [summitpost forums](https://www.summitpost.org/phpBB3/). For Europe, try this [forum topic](http://www.summitpost.org/phpBB3/europe-f56.html) from that website.

Answer (score 0):

For France and Switzerland, you can try category "Partenaires : Alpinisme, cascade de glace" (mountaineering & icefall) on [camptocamp.org](https://forum.camptocamp.org/c/partenaires/partenaires-alpinisme-cascade-de-glace) forums.

It's mainly a french-speaking forum, so you should get better results if you post in this category. There is also an [english](https://forum.camptocamp.org/c/english/mountaineering) section for mountaineering, but it's less active.